# Implicit dependencies to find go stdlib packages

Tags: go

I have a stripped down environment, where I want to use go at a custom path.

`printenv` gives me:

```
GOOS=linux
GOROOT=/mygo
GOHOSTOS=linux
GOARCH=amd64
TMPDIR=/mytmp
GOHOSTARCH=amd64
GOPATH=/mysrcs
PWD=/home/andreas
```

Now if I try to compile go code, it fails to find the stdlib:

```
could not import fmt (cannot find package "fmt" in any of:
/mygo/src/fmt (from $GOROOT)
```

If I do `find /mygo | grep fmt`, I get:

```
/mygo/pkg/linux_amd64/fmt.a
```

When I use the system go (normal bash environment), it works fine. What implicit dependencies does go need to find the stdlib packages?

Comment: What is a "custom go"? You always need the source tree available to compile.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by _source tree_?

Comment: The std lib source files. Everything under `GOROOT/src`.

Comment: Ok, can you then please explain what `pkg` is for? Why have precompiled if you still need sources?

Comment: Think of `pkg/` only as a cache. You still need sources to know if the compiled artifact is up to date, and even in the very rare case of binary-only packages you still need a source file to indicate it as such. Now with the upcoming addition of `GOCACHE`, `pkg` won't be used much at all by the `go` tool.

Comment: Thanks @JimB for clearing that up. Do you by any chance have link to docs for `pkg` and/or `GOCACHE`? And cookie-points for using _Markdown_ in comments!

Comment: `GOCACHE` isn't really documented yet, but will probably be mentioned in the [Build & Install release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.10#build) (or `go help cache` will at least be created). The [workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) `pkg` directory isn't mentioned much in the documentation, because users don't really interact with it except in the case of [Binary Only Packages](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages) (which again, are rarely used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JimB, I managed to get it working.

I indeed want [binary-only packaging](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages) of stdlib.
Discussion online is that `$GOROOT/pkg` is a valid use-case for binary distribution, while `$GOPATH/pkg` might get deprecated soonish, so beware.

If you want to provide binary-only packages, https://github.com/tcnksm/go-binary-only-package shows how to create (annotated) `src` directory structure, in order for go to stop searching for source files.